# Confusion in the relationship between compact riemann surfaces and complex algebraic curves

Tags: complex-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

I know that every compact Riemann surface is algebraic, i.e. every compact Riemann surface is isomorphic
to a smooth projective complex curve, not necessarily plane (take e.g. the twisted cubic).

However, I have encountered the following proposition in Freitag's "Complex analysis 2":

> Every connected compact Riemann surface is biholomorphically equivalent to the Riemann surface which is associated with an irreducible polynomial $P(z,w)\in \mathbb{C}[z,w]$

This proposition confuses me deeply: what about Riemann surface associated with the twisted cubic? Is it biholomorphically equivalent to the R.S. of a plane curve? How can it be so?

Comment: I don't really know about the analytic study of curves, but is a biholomorphism necessarily an algebraic isomorphism? I imagine this is covered in GAGA or something.

Comment: Isn't the twisted cubic a rational (genus zero) curve?

Comment: @AnginaSeng Yes, but I do not see how that helps

Comment: @D.Brogan Well, two biholomorphically equivalent riemann surfaces have isomorphic function fields, which in turn implies (if they are smooth algebraic curves) that they are algebraically isomorphic, right?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the answer to this question: [Is every algebraic curve birational to a planar curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170798/is-every-algebraic-curve-birational-to-a-planar-curve).

It's a fairly short argument that every curve is birational to a planar one. Since birational maps between smooth curves are isomorphisms, I think this answers your question. It seems that the statement "not necessarily planar" is false in your statement. The reason that the twisted cubic is not a counterexample is because it is the image of an embedding $\mathbb P^1\to \mathbb P^3$ and hence is isomorphic to a line in the plane.